# Does the return process cast/convert the type required to a result according to the C standard, or is that only supported in certain implementations?

Tags: c

I noticed that

```
float f; 
[..]
printf("%i\n", f);
```

is not reasonable

but

```
printf("%i\n", (int)f);
```

is

but also

```
int func(float f) {
    return f;
}
```

is ok on

```
printf("%i\n", func(f));
```

Is that conversion/casting that is being done by the return process or the function supported by the standard, or does it ideally need

```
int func(float f) {
    return (int) f;
}
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conversion is standard.  The relevant part of the ISO C99 standard is in section 6.8.6.4, paragraph 3:

> If the expression has a type different
>   from the return type of the function
>   in which it appears, the value is
>   converted as if by assignment to an
>   object having the return type of the
>   function.

So it's implicitly converted, in the same way that it is in this assignment:

```
float f = 3.0f;
int i;

i = f;
```

The allowed conversions are:

- the return type has qualified or unqualified arithmetic type and the expression has
  arithmetic type;
- the return type has a qualified or unqualified version of a structure or union type
  compatible with the type of the expression;
- the return type and expression are both pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the return type has all the qualifiers of the expression type;
- one of the return type or expression is a pointer to an object or incomplete type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of `void`, and the return type has all the qualifiers of the expression type;
- the return type is a pointer and the expression is a null pointer constant; or
- the return type has type `_Bool` and the expression is a pointer.

(Your example matches the first one - both `int` and `float` are arithmetic types)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that; I was searching the pdf but didn't find it quickly enough.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when an expression has a certain numeric type, and its context expects a different numeric type, the appropriate conversion will happen automatically. This applies in cases such as:

```
void f(float);
void g(long);
int i = 3;
f(i); /*function call, with a prototype in scope*/
g(i); /*ditto*/
double d = i; /*assignment*/
```

This principle also applies to the expression `return` instruction.

This principle does *not* apply to variadic functions such as `printf`. The reason is that the proper conversions depend on the format string, and the compiler is not required to analyze the format string; in fact, if the format is not a string literal, the compiler usually can't analyze it. So all the casts are necessary in the following `printf` call:

```
int i = 3;
float f = 1.5;
printf("%ld %f %d\n", (long)i, (double)i, (int)f);
```

However, due to promotions (`char` and `short` are promoted to `int`, `float` is promoted to `double`) and to the fact that `%c` expects an `int`, no casts are nessary in the following `printf` call:

```
char c = 'a';
float f = 1.5;
printf("%c %d %f", c, c, f);
```