# What happens to return value when its type differs from the declared return type?

Tags: c, return-value

Why is my simple C program printing "hello world" and being compiled with no errors and is running fine when I gave a floating point number next to return statement? Shouldn't it be an error to do so?

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("hello world");
    return 2.1;
}
```

Comment: why it should give error, it will give only warning

Comment: implicitly it will convert float to int

Comment: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/995714)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the return process cast/convert the type required to a result according to the C standard, or is that only supported in certain implementations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457497/does-the-return-process-cast-convert-the-type-required-to-a-result-according-to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the same reason of

```
int main(void)
{
    // ...
    int x = 2.1;

    // ...
   return x;
}
```

This is called [implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion).

Comment: this question is about C, so the correct link should be http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Thanks, didn't find it straight off from google.

Comment: you can find the C version at the end of each C++ page

Answer (score 3):

When you return a different type from the declared type of the function, the value is automatically converted to the declared type. So it's equivalent to doing:

```
return (int) 2.1;
```

Comment: I also want to ask that "why main function in c language returns only  integer but not float pointing number or a string"

Comment: @suryadutt because it's the error code returned to the OS, which is not a float

Comment: @venki The answer you link refers to C++ (which differs slightly from C in this respect).

Comment: @suryadutt: The language definition mandates that `main` return an `int`. Note that the return value of `main` is usually a status code for the runtime environment, so it makes sense for it to be an integer type.  Per section 5.1.2.2.1 of the [C language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), an implementation *may* provide an alternate signature for `main`, which it *must* document (although the ones I've seen usually change the number of arguments to `main`, not its return type).

Answer (score 1):

The return code will be casted automatically on return.
The long version is

```
return (int) 2.1;
```

Comment: Nitpick: the return value will be implicitly converted, not automatically casted.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will return an integer because the compiler will take care of casting the float into an integer.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal as the value well be implicitly converted to your declared type. the compiler will not mind but you'll get unexpected results at the runtime in general and in this specific case the casting to (int).